# fullcalendar Moment _ordinalParse is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

everyone, please help me with the code. I am trying to send an ajax after creating a new record in the calendar. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var events = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;

        for(var i in events)
        {
            if(events[i].allDay === "false")
            {
                events[i].allDay = false;
            }

            if(events[i].allDay === "true")
            {
                events[i].allDay = true;
            }
        }

        var calendar = $('#calendar');
        var aId = calendar.attr('aId');

        calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: events,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var title = prompt('Заглавие:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    };

                //var newDate = new Date(formatDate(eventData.start));


                    $.post(
                        "/panel/agentTasks/addEvent"
                        , {
                            type: 'add',
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            aId: aId,
                            allDay: allDay
                        }, function( data ) {
                            if(data === 'success');
                            //location.reload();
                        }, "json");

                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            timeFormat: {
                agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
            },
            slotMinutes: 15,
            allDayText: 'за целия ден',
            eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                $.post(
                    "/panel/agentTasks/addEvent"
                    , {
                        type: 'resize',
                        end: moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'),
                        id: event.id
                    });

            },
            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                var title = prompt('Заглавие:', event.title);

                if (title && event.id){
                    event.title = title;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/panel/agentTasks/addEvent',
                        data: 'type=changeTitle&title='+title+'&eventId='+event.id,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response.status == 'success')
                                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                        //странно, но не работи, може би защото е стара версия на плъгина, за това ще презаредя страницата; криво решение, но поне докато се открие друго решение;
                                location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function(e){
                            alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            eventDrop: function(event) {
                $.post(
                    "/panel/agentTasks/addEvent"
                    , {
                        type: 'resetDate',
                        title: event.title,
                        start: moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'),
                        end: moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'),
                        id: event.id,
                        allDay: event.allDay
                    }
                );
            },
            eventDragStop: function(event,jsEvent) {

                var trashEl = $('#calendarTrash');
                var ofs = trashEl.offset();

                var x1 = ofs.left;
                var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
                var y1 = ofs.top;
                var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

                if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX<= x2 &&
                    jsEvent.pageY>= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {

                    var r = confirm('Сигурен ли сте, че искате да изтриете?');
                    if(r === true){
                        $.post(
                            "/panel/agentTasks/addEvent"
                            , {
                                type: 'deleteDate',
                                id: event.id
                            }
                        );

                        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                    }

                }

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Everything else is working fine. I am using the latest fullcalendar version. The error i get - "TypeError: this._ordinalParse is undefined". Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say it has to do with the formatting of your dates, but hard to tell with so much code. Could you try to create a minimal example that reproduces your error, or at least indicate which line(s) trigger(s) the error?

Comment: I am sorry, my bad, first post here :)  The particular problem is with the 'select' part of the fullcalendar, the ajax